# Thunderbird: messenger.messages.listAttachments returns empty array when using pgp

Tags: javascript, pgp, thunderbird

I am trying to use the paperless addon for thunderbird: https://github.com/Niach/paperless-thunderbird-extension

My mail account has a PGP key linked to it. When I click on an email, I can view the attachments without problems and they are listed correctly.

However, when the addon calls

```
let message = await messenger.messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessage(tabs[0].id);
const attachments = await messenger.messages.listAttachments(message.id);
```

an empty array is returned.

When using another account that is not using pgp, the attachments are returned as expected.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? The only other answer I found is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610640/10843051, which does not answer the question why it does not work.